# Would it be possible to make a wheel out of ferrofluids?

Tags: science-fiction, transportation, vehicles

Imagine a vehicle, with wheels, the center of the wheel is going to be piece of electromagnet that looks like a egg churner/or a paddle wheel, around it, instead of rubber, it's going to be A LOT of ferrofluid.

In my imagination, if I make sure the magnet is plugged in, its turning would make the ferrofluid slush in a circle, but it would not spill everywhere because it would stick to the magnet, therefore making an all-terrain wheel.

let's ignore the impact of having ferrofluid everywhere, and how much it would cost, would something like this even work?

Comment: I was also thinking if it is possible to not use ferrofluid, instead having some very sticky liquid, which's surface tension is stronger then the force of its stickyness, which means i can just churn the liquid without the ferrofluid part, and potentially even having the wheel stick on ceilings and walls.

Comment: what is it's freezing point?

Comment: The problem with this sort of logic is that trying to do something cool takes precedence over common sense. The energy required to make the ferrofluid solid enough to act as a practical tire is breathtaking compared to rubber and air. But the real question is this: does that matter? Who cares if it does or doesn't work in the Real World? Our mandate is to help you build rules for an imaginary world and our goal is suspension-of-disbelief, not Real World manufacturability. We can help you reach that goal, but if all you're interested in is the engineering plausibility, the answer is no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it won't work.

- There will always be a level of stress which will make the fluid leave the magnet.
- To transfer the torque from the wheel axle to the surface, the wheel needs to grip onto it. Your magnet ensure the adherence of the fluid to the axle, not to the ground.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe, but the power transfer from the axle to the surface would be pitiful. Luckily the fundamental concept isn't new so the general effect is a known quantity.

Old school automatic transmissions are based around fluid clutches, the simplified concept is that input torque is added to a relatively high viscosity fluid, the spinning of which rotates the output shaft. They're low efficiency and that's with a system that's designed to transfer the power with minimal separation between input and output shafts.

Your system is going to have the axle spinning in your ferrofluid wheels like the input of a fluid clutch, if you spin the axle fast enough some of the torque will eventually be transferred into forward propulsion. If there's much resistance to the movement, like a slight incline, the effect will probably be negligible. For best drive you'll want a thin skin of ferrofluid over the magnetic wheel which will be terrible for uneven surfaces, making the exercise futile.

Answer (score 3):

"it would not spill everywhere because it would stick to the magnet": Ferrofluid is *incredibly* messy, and sticks to just about anything. You'd leave a ferrofluid trail everywhrere, and the wheels would quickly turn into a sort of ferrofluid-based mud full of anything small enough to cling to the magnet by its coating of ferrofluid.

Perhaps, with some tough, low-friction membrane and perhaps an additional slime component, you could produce something like the foot of a snail or slug. I don't see any obvious reasons why you'd do this, but it'd likely work better than a wheel made of exposed ferrofluid.